# Sitecore - 301 redirection for similar URLs

Tags: iis, sitecore, redirect

As suggested by SEO, I'm trying to redirect similar URLs to one single URL.
For example,

1) http://www.example.com/en/contact-us

2) http://www.example.com/en/contact%20us

3) **http://www.example.com/en/contact-us/**

Above three URLs take us to the same item in Sitecore. So I would like to make the URL in bold to be the main URL and other two URLs should have a 301 redirection to it.

I tried adding rewrite rule in IIS and could get the first URL to redirect. However, the second URL is not redirecting to the 3rd URL. See below config.

Web.config

```
<rewrite>    
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect rule">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*example\.com.*" />
              <add input="{ExamplePermanent:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" 
                     redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
    </rules>
    <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config" />
</rewrite>
```

rewritemaps.config

```
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="ExamplePermanent">
      <add key="/en/contact-us" value="/en/contact-us/" />
      <add key="/en/contact%20us" value="/en/contact-us/" />
  </rewriteMap>
<rewriteMaps>
```

Is there any configuration that needs to be done in order to make the 2nd URL redirect with 301?

Comment: What are you redirect rules? Paste your config

Comment: I have updated the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS will decode %20 to a space, so just replace that with space in rewritemaps:

```
 <add key="/en/contact us" value="/en/contact-us/" />
```

Comment: I had already added a space but it wasn't working. Required App pool recycle to get it working in local. And an app service restart in Azure.